# Не происходит обработки после выбора файла на html странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер

пишу расширение для браузера. В main.html записал инпут.

```html
<br>
</br>
<input id="fileInput" type="file" size="50" onchange="onFilesSelect(event)">
<div id="fileOutput"></div>
<br>
</br>
```

в main.js у меня код типа такого

```js
(function($){

function ajaxStart(){
$('#progress').show();
}

function ajaxStop(){
$('#progress').hide();
}

function parserGo(){
ajaxStart();
var mask=$('input#inputer').val();
var site=$('input#inputSite').val();
var b = $.ajax('https://www.google.ru/search?q= '+mask+' '+site);

//Парсинг
//.....
}

$(function(){
$('#progress').hide();
$('#starter').click(parserGo);

});
})(jQuery);
```

Как видно парсинг начинается с нажатия кнопки. До парсинга мне надо выбрать файл в который я буду заносить информацию. Добавляю в любое место в коде main.js это

```js
function onFilesSelect(e) {
 alert("Loaded"); 
}
```

никакой реакции после выбора файла. Что я делаю не так?

Вот что нашел в сетях...

```js
var filesExt = ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'htm']; // массив расширений
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
var parts = $(this).val().split('.');
if(filesExt.join().search(parts[parts.length - 1]) != -1){
    alert('Good!');
} else {
    alert('WTF?!');
}
})
```

Заработало, теперь я хочу получить текст из файла. Как теперь вытащить внутренности файла выбранного в инпут?

Comment: Нашел способ мне кажется... отредактировал.

Comment: Добавил к вопросу. Не могу достать текст из файла выбранного в инпут.